# How to center an image in tkinter with PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to center an image in tkinter canvas. The only thing I could think of is using `anchor = 'c'` but that does not seem to work. I have also tried using it on the `stage`.

```
def newsetup(filelocation):
    global width, height
    
    for widgets in root.winfo_children():
        widgets.destroy()

    stage = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 700, highlightbackground = 'red', highlightthickness = 2)
    stage.pack()

    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filelocation)) 
    stage.create_image(stage.winfo_width() + 2, stage.winfo_height() + 2, image = imgtk, anchor = CENTER)
    stage.image = imgtk
```

Comment: maybe you should also set `global stage`

Comment: if you use position `stage.winfo_width() + 2, stage_winfo_height() + 2` then it may display it in place which you can't see. First try different position. OR maybe you needed `/` instead of `+` like `stage.winfo_width() / 2, stage_winfo_height() / 2` - to put in center of canvas

Comment: don't you get errors when you run it in console? You forgot value in `anchor=...`, You  need dot after `stage` in `stage_winfo_height()`

Comment: I don't know how I got no error actually... The `anchor =`  was me doing some testing and forgot to remove it. I found out the image is in a location I can't see. I now want to center the image on the canvas. I have edited the question

Comment: if you want to cetner then use `/` instead of `+`  - `stage.winfo_width()/2, stage.winfo_height()/2`

Comment: if you put iamge at start (before `mainloop`) then you may need also `root.update()` to force `mainloop` to calculate correct `width`, `height` for `Canvas`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to center on canvas then you need

```
stage.winfo_width()/2, stage.winfo_height()/2
```

(even without `anchor=` which as default has value `center`)

But if you put image before it runs `mainloop()` then `stage.winfo_width()` `stage.winfo_height()` gives `0,0` instead of expected `width, height` (because `mainloop` creates window and it sets all sizes for widgets) and it may need `root.update()` to run `mainloop` once and it will calculate all sizes.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = tk.Tk()

stage = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=700)
stage.pack()

root.update()  # force `mainloop()` to calculate current `width`, `height` for canvas
               # and later `stage.winfo_width()` `stage.winfo_height()` will get correct values instead `0`
    
#imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('lenna.png'))
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='lenna.png')

stage.create_image((stage.winfo_width()/2, stage.winfo_height()/2), image=imgtk, anchor='center')
stage.image = imgtk

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

---

Image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia.

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep it centered when you resize window then you can bind event `<Configure>` to canvas and it will execute assigned function - and it can move image.

But it needs `image ID` which you can get when you create image

```
img_id = stage.create_image(...)
```

Because `<Configure>` is executed when it creates window so code doesn't need `root.update()` because `on_resize()` will set correct position at start.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# --- functions ---

def on_resize(event):
    # it respects anchor
    x = event.width/2  
    y = event.height/2
    stage.coords(img_id, x, y)  
    
    # it DOESN'T respects anchor so you have to add offset
    #x = (event.width - imgtk.width())/2  
    #y = (event.height - imgtk.height())/2
    #stage.moveto(img_id, x, y)  # doesn't respect anchor

    #stage.itemconfigure(img_id, ...)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

stage = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=700)
stage.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

#root.update()  # force `mainloop()` to calculate current `width`, `height` for canvas
               # and later `stage.winfo_width()` `stage.winfo_height()` will get correct values instead `0`
    
#imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('lenna.png'))
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file='lenna.png')

img_id = stage.create_image((stage.winfo_width()/2, stage.winfo_height()/2), image=imgtk, anchor='center')
stage.image = imgtk

stage.bind('<Configure>', on_resize)  # run function when Canvas change size

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would I be able to update the center if the user changes the size of the window, which would also effect the canvas size

Comment: first you need `image_id` which you get `image_id = stace.create_image(...)`. Next you can use `stage.bind('<Configure>", function)` to run `def function(event)` when it changes size. And this function should use this `image_id` with `stage.itemconfing(image_id, ...)` or `stage.moveto(image_id, ....)` (but this doesn't respect `anchor`)

Comment: I added example which center image when you resize window. In similar way you can resize window when you resize window - but it need `PIL` to resize image and use `itemconfig(item_id, image=PhotoImage(...))` to replace image.

Comment: Yep it works... I did not know tkinter had all these features it is amazing... also thanks